# react + tailwind (popover menu) - request about component refactoring tips?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I finished my first component based on headlessui and popover (link: https://headlessui.com/react/popover).

I asked our community about look at my component:

- live: https://loquacious-sherbet-abe60f.netlify.app/
- git:  https://github.com/robokonk/tailwind-menu/blob/main/src/components/Header.tsx

Which element I should refactor and how (I grateful for the tip and link for documentation about selected hint))

Additionaly I wanted simpifly line 4 to 94, and put this function in one json like:

```
const iconData = [
  iconOne: `<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className="w-6 h-6"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
      strokeWidth={2}
    >
      <path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
      />
    </svg>`
]
```

But I can't render this icon, how I should do it?

I also see, that I can simplify it (line 140 to 147):

```
interface itemProps {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  description: string;
  icon: any;
}

function menuPosition(item: itemProps, index: number) {
```

And prepare interface like:

```
interface menuProps {
  index:number,
  item: itemProps
}

interface itemProps {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  description: string;
  icon: any;
}
```

But when I changed my code, I get information from line: 192:

```
return menuPosition(item, index);
```

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)`

- How I should fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how moving an svg into a string simplify the code. You can, for example, take a common parts into `GenericIcon` function:

```
function GenericIcon(path: string) {
  return () => (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className="w-6 h-6"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
      strokeWidth={2}
    >
      <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d={path} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

Then declare the icons:

```
const IconMenu = GenericIcon("M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16");
const IconMenuClose = GenericIcon("M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12");
...
```

And use them like this:

```
<IconMenu />
```

Regarding the `menuPosition` question. My opinion: better to leave it as is.

P.S. The component looks cool!

Comment: Thanks, I do:
- declarate the icons, as you recommend
- added deconstructing

But I have problem with rendering this icon:
- this is code:
https://pastebin.com/GF90r2Pp
- my icons at the moment not will generated, how it fix?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RkLnb9B0K8Zl_6e4_hirMPB-Z6SXOu4D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @robokonk Inside the `menuPositionData` you need the real components. So remove quotes like this: `icon: <IconProduct />`. You can also reference the names: `icon: IconProduct` an then create elements inside the `menuPosition` function: `{React.createElement(icon)}`. If your data is dynamic (from API for example) and all you have is srting then the esiest approach is to map strings to component names one to one: `const mapping = { "IconProduct": IconProduct, ... }` and create them with `React.createElement(mapping[iconName])`.